# Is there a way to analyze a PostgreSQL query to make sure that the result only contains columns from a single table?

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, abstract-syntax-tree

I'd like to find a way to determine if a specific PostgreSQL query only returns results that contains non-derived columns from a single table.

For example, the following query would meet the criteria:

- `SELECT * FROM users;`

But the following queries would not:

- `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users;`
- `SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN organizations ON user_id;`

If there are any JavaScript libraries that do this, that would be especially helpful. I am also open to ideas on how to parse the query's AST to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Why wouldn't `select count(*) from users;` not qualify? There's only one table involved.

Comment: I would like non-derived and non-computed columns such as COUNT, AVG, etc. Only the columns that should be in the actual `users` table should be returned.

Comment: Why? What's the point? This is a very broad question and it's pretty likely to end up being closed if you don't explain what you're actually trying to do, at least.

Comment: I am working on a SQL client that lets users inline edit the results of a query (think in the form of a spreadsheet). For that to work unambiguously, each column in the result row needs to map directly to a specific column in the table.

Comment: It might be easier to look at the *results* of the query and inspect the metadata to check whether the result set matches up with the "schema" of the spreadsheet.